# How to convert fileData from str to file type in Python?

Tags: python, string, io, binary

I've got this file data which I read from an API as base64 and converted to regular file data using the following:

```
base64FileData = attachmentObj.data['data']
fileData = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64FileData.encode('UTF-8'))
print type(fileData)  # prints out <type 'str'>
```

Since I need the file in binary to further process it, I can then store it and read it back out as follows:

```
print type(fileData)  # prints out <type 'str'>
with open('thefile.pdf', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fileData)
with open('thefile.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    print type(f)  # prints out <type 'file'>, which I actually need.
```

This works, but seeing there is no need to actually store the file, this seems like one of the worst pieces of code I've ever seen.

Does anybody know how I can convert the initial fileData to a type `'file'` without storing it and reading it back out? All tips are welcome!

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. Writing data to a file doesn't "convert it to binary". Are you saying you need to be able to present a file handle to some function that only works with files?

Comment: @AndrewMedico - The thing is that in the library I use, there is a test which does `if type(fileData) is str:`. If it is a string, it thinks it is a filename and tries to open the file with the regular Python `open()`. Therefore I need the fileData to be of type `file`, and not of type `str`. I can do this as described by writing to a file using `open()` and then opening that same file again. But there must be a better way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [StringIO / cStringIO modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html). They present a file interface to an existing buffer (string) in memory. This will let you pass your data to the library without writing a temp file.

For example:

```
import StringIO

...

base64FileData = attachmentObj.data['data']
fileData = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64FileData.encode('UTF-8'))

memoryFile = StringIO.StringIO(fileData)

someFunctionThatOperatesOnFileObjects(memoryFile)
```